# Iron Router being called two times with mongo find

Tags: meteor

I have a router being called two times if I execute some find. If I remove the find statement the router only call once (which is what I expect in the other case).

Router config:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    console.log("ROUTE!");
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
        Router.go("login");
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}, {
    except: ['login', 'signup']
});
```

My route:

```
Router.route("/", function() {
    this.subscribe("games");

    var lastDay = Games.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    console.log(lastDay);

    this.render("stats", {
        data: function() {
            return { 
                games: Games.find()
            };
        }
    });
}, { name: "stats" });
```

With lastDay find, the route is called two times. First undefined as result, second time I get the correct object. 
Removing lastDay statement, the router works fine.

**Update:** Tried to make the findOne in a helper, console.log it, and it is calling twice too! First undefined, second time the object.

Comment: try this return { 
                games: Games.find(), lastDay: Games.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
            };

Comment: @Nakib yes, this works. But I want the lastDay result to use it in my games: Games.find().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using waitOn to subscribe.

```
Router.route("/", {
    name: "stats",
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("games");
    }, 
    action: function() {
        var lastDay = Games.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});

        this.render("stats", {
            data: function() {
                return {
                    games: Games.find()   
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the result instead of storing in the variable

```
Router.route("/", function() {
    this.subscribe("games");


    this.render("stats", {
        data: function() {
            return { 
                games: Games.find({$gt:Games.findOne({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).createdAt})
            };
        }
    });
}, { name: "stats" });
```

Comment: I can't. What I pretend to do with games is a find with createdAt $gte lastDay.

Comment: Update: Tried to make the findOne in a helper, and it is calling twice too! First undefined, second time the object.

Comment: two times again... It is like search once, something changes it, and the reactiveness occurs with the correct data. But what is changing?

Comment: try getting data on waitOn and when its ready pass it to render

Comment: Well, I fixed it, putting the subscription in waitOn... Check my own fix.